# Vlc c#, Subtitle, Dokumentation Vlc

Tags: c#, vlc, subtitle

I have a question, I read all the documentation, but I do not understand, how can I use all that, I have DB and link from movie and from subtitle to DB, I can go to VLC movie, but I can not get subtitle, I've tried everything possible, if anyone has experience with documentation from VLC, help.

[Vlc Documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/)

I have tried:

for example:

```
string movie = "file:///D:/1.avi" + " --sub-file=file:///D:/1.txt"

string movie = "file:///D:/1.avi" + " :sub-file = file:///D:/1.txt"
vlcPlayer.playliste.add (movie);
vlcPlayer.playliste.play ();
```

everything works, play, pause, stop .... only subtitle is missing

and by

```
int track = vlcPlayer.subtitle.track.count;
```

is always -1;

```
int sub = vlcPlayer.video.subtitle.count;
```

is always 0;

but by

```
int sum = vlcPlayer.playlist.count;
```

is 2 but if i use

```
vlcPlayer.playlist.playitem (1);
```

it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Which C# wrapper are you using?

Try [`libvlc_media_player_add_slave`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gad7f50e13e7b96667bb0a37383c1d4c03)